# Event duration prediction in R? need tips for methods and packages

Tags: r, methods, time, modeling, prediction

I have a general question of methodology. 
I have to create a model to predict when/after how many days of therapy a patient reaches a certain value. I have  data  of this  value from tight laboratory controls  and also information on some influence variables. But now I'm at a loss and I don't know how to do it best, so that in the end there will be something that can be used to make predictions for new patients when this threshold is reached, or as a binary variable when the value is not longer detectable.

The more I read about the topic, the more unsure I am about the optimal method.

Comment: It seems like a simple `lm` or `glm` along with corresponding `predict.lm` or `predict.glm` should work fine? The call can be enclosed in a function that takes the no. of days or other influece variables you mentioned, as inputs. You can set upper and lower bounds for any/all of those inputs, outside of which the prediction can not be made.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try, but I am afraid, that this seems to be too easy. But maybe thst is just my stupid head that always makes me doubt :-) thank you